# MYSQL: Select rows in range of hours by field timestamp

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a field type `TIMESTAMP` with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as predeterminate (`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`) and I need select all rows from `13:00:00` to `15:00:00` of the all days.

I try to:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE rowDate BETWEEN '13:00:00' AND '15:00:00';
```

But i don't get any row.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `TIME` function to extract the time component of the timestamp:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE TIME(rowDate) BETWEEN '13:00:00' AND '15:00:00';
```

Comment: `HOUR()` function is also applicable in his case.

Comment: Thank you, i don't know function TIME. Thanks.